# Release build Windows Phone 8 library for Any CPU change to x86

Tags: dll, windows-phone-8, anycpu

Strange configuration which I can't seem to understand.

I have a Windows Phone 8 library that I want to build for Any CPU, this works fine when I am selecting Debug, but soon as I choose Release configuration changes the platform to x86.
I can change it to Any CPU, save and exit options but if you open it again it is switched back to Active (x86).

What do I miss? The proper way to distribute Windows Phone libraries?

Regards.

Comment: The Platform name is not relevant for managed libraries, the jitter figures it out at runtime.  You need to mention what *other* kind of projects you have in the solution, Platform matters a great deal to C++ projects for example.

Comment: No, the target is for Windows 8 projects. So I will provide this library to use in Windows 8 C# projects.

Comment: If this is a C# library to be used in a C# Store app then the pragmatic solution is to just remove platforms that you have no use for and only keep AnyCPU.

Comment: Thanks it works with changing the Platform from the Configuration Manager in Solution not in project.